# Converting Java to Scala durations

Tags: scala, config, duration, scala-java-interop

Is there an elegant way to convert `java.time.Duration` to `scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration`?

I am trying to do the following simple use of Config in Scala:

`val d = ConfigFactory.load().getDuration("application.someTimeout")`

However I don't see any simple way to use the result in Scala.
Certainly hope the good people of Typesafe didn't expect me to do this:

`FiniteDuration(d.getNano, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)`

Edit: Note the line has a bug, which proves the point. See the selected answer below.

Comment: What is wrong with the shown solution? This is easy and understandable. Wrap it in a function/create an implicit conversion if it is not short enough for you.

Comment: @sschaef the bothering bit is a supposedy "scala-friendly" library to spit out Java types, but this isn't a new thing when speaking of Config.

Comment: Typesafe Config is serving both Java and Scala clients, by its project definition. I agree that having to use an implicit conversion is a bit surprising. I cover this within the MyConfig singleton, so the application code will never need to know. One should not sprinkle raw Typesafe Config accesses in application level code.

Comment: For some use, reading the config as certain units (normally ms) might be sufficient. Then simply '.toMillis' will do the trick. This still allows the configuration files to provide any unit that is nice for us humans.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I don't know whether an explicit conversion is the only way, but if you want to do it right

```
FiniteDuration(d.toNanos, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
```

`toNanos` will return the total duration, while `getNano` will only return the nanoseconds component, which is not what you want.

E.g.

```
import java.time.Duration
import jata.time.temporal.ChronoUnit
Duration.of(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS).getNano // 0
Duration.of(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS).toNanos  // 3600000000000L
```

That being said, you can also roll your own implicit conversion

```
implicit def asFiniteDuration(d: java.time.Duration) =
  scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.fromNanos(d.toNanos)
```

and when you have it in scope:

```
val d: FiniteDuration = ConfigFactory.load().getDuration("application.someTimeout")
```

Answer (score 59):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, there is a dedicated [`DurationConverter`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/DurationConverters$.html) from java's `Duration` to scala's `FiniteDuration` (and vice versa):

```
import scala.jdk.DurationConverters._

// val javaDuration = java.time.Duration.ofNanos(123456)
javaDuration.toScala
// scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration = 123456 nanoseconds
```

Comment: same package has converter from Scala to Java Duration as well

Answer (score 23):

I don't know any better way, but you can make it a bit shorter:

```
Duration.fromNanos(d.toNanos)
```

and also wrap it into an implicit conversion yourself

```
implicit def toFiniteDuration(d: java.time.Duration): FiniteDuration = Duration.fromNanos(d.toNanos)
```

(changed `d.toNano` to `d.toNanos`)

Answer (score 8):

There is a function for this in `scala-java8-compat`

in build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-java8-compat" % "0.9.0"
```

```
import scala.compat.java8.DurationConverters._

val javaDuration: java.time.Duration = ???
val scalaDuration: FiniteDuration = javaDuration.toScala
```